# Vue template fires more than once when used, i think i need a unique key somewhere

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to implement font-awesome-picker to a website that i am making using vue2/php/mysql, but within standard js scripting, so no imports, .vue etc.
The script i am trying to add is taken from here: https://github.com/laistomazz/font-awesome-picker
The problem that i am facing is that i have 3 columns that have a title and an icon picker next it, that will allow the user to select 1 icon for each title. It is kinda working well...but if the same icon is used in 2 different columns then any time the user clicks again any of the 2 icons both instances of the picker will fire up, thus showing 2 popups. I need to somehow make them unique.

I've tried using 
    :key="list.id"
or 
    v-for="icon in icons" :icon:icon :key="icon" 
but nothing worked. Somehow i have to separate all the instances (i think) so they are unique.
This is the template code:

```
Vue.component('font-awesome-picker', {
template: ' <div><div class="iconPicker__header"><input type="text" class="form-control" :placeholder="searchPlaceholder" @keyup="filterIcons($event)"  @blur="resetNew" @keydown.esc="resetNew"></div><div class="iconPicker__body"><div class="iconPicker__icons"><a  href="#" @click.stop.prevent="getIcon(icon)" :class="`item ${selected === icon ? \'selected\' : \'\'}`" v-for="icon in icons" :key="icon"><i :class="\'fa \'+icon"></i></a></div></div></div>',
name: 'fontAwesomePicker',
props: ['seachbox','parentdata'],
data () {
    return {
        selected: '',
        icons,
    listobj: {
      type: Object
    }
    };
},
computed: {
    searchPlaceholder () {
        return this.seachbox || 'search box';
    },
},
methods: {
  resetNew () {
      vm.addNewTo = null;
  },
    getIcon (icon) {
        this.selected = icon;
        this.getContent(this.selected);
    },
    getContent (icon) {
        const iconContent = window
            .getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(`.fa.${icon}`), ':before')
            .getPropertyValue('content');
        this.convert(iconContent);
    },
    convert (value) {
        const newValue = value
            .charCodeAt(1)
            .toString(10)
            .replace(/\D/g, '');

        let hexValue = Number(newValue).toString(16);

        while (hexValue.length < 4) {
            hexValue = `0${hexValue}`;
        }

        this.selecticon(hexValue.toUpperCase());
    },
    selecticon (value) {
        this.listobj = this.$props.parentdata;
        const result = {
            className: this.selected,
            cssValue: value,
            listobj: this.listobj
        };
        this.$emit('selecticon', result);
    },
    filterIcons (event) {
        const search = event.target.value.trim();
        let filter = [];

        if (search.length > 3) {
            filter = icons.filter((item) => {
                const regex = new RegExp(search, 'gi');
                return item.match(regex);
            });
        }else{
            this.icons = icons;
        }

        if (filter.length > 0) {
            this.icons = filter;
        }
    }
},
});
```

I've setup a fiddle with the problem here: 
    https://jsfiddle.net/3yxk1ahb/1/
Just pick the same icon in both cases, and then click any of the icons again. You'll see that the popups opens for both columns.

How can i separate the pickers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is in your `@click` and `v-show`

you should use `list.id` instead of `list.icon` (i.e `@click="addNewTo = list.id"`)

working fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/q513mhwt/

Comment: omg, i am such an idiot. Thank you @Ja9ad335h !!
It was driving me crazy